# startx "if statement" in .xinitrc not working

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

Here is my .xinitrc in my ~ (HOME) folder:

```
#!/bin/bash

# set wallpaper
feh --bg-fill ~/Pictures/wallpapers/allstars.jpg

# default cursor
xsetroot -cursor_name left_ptr &

wm() {
        if [ $1 != 'i3' ]
        then     
            # status bar
            ~/bin/bar_scripts/bar_info.sh | dzen2 -w 1366 -p 5 &
        fi

        # load x resources
        xrdb -load ~/.Xresources &

        # keybindings
        xbindkeys

        # set WM name
        xsetroot -name $1

        # spawn window manager
        exec $1
}

wm $1
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to start whichever window manager I want by passing it as an argument in `startx ~/.xinitrc {wm}`. But I also use Dzen as a status bar, but I don't want it to spawn when I'm using i3, since it already has a status bar I'm fine with.

But it doesn't work as it's currently written. I've made a *test.sh* to just run the if statement and it catches the argument just fine. So I don't know what's different about *.xinitrc* that I need to account for.

Comment: I would like to suggest you to ask questions like this here:
[Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com).

Comment: In _what way exactly_ does it not work?

Comment: Is a second argument processed from `startx`?

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: @Kusalananda so to launch my environment I enter `# startx ~/.xinitrc i3` or `# startx ~/.xinitrc openbox`. To test the if statement, I have it the true case, `[ $1 == 'i3' ]` apply one wallpaper, and the else case apply a different wallpaper. The else is triggering right now when I pass `i3`.

Comment: @Cyrus from what I've read, if you don't specify a **.xinitrc** then the first argument is **xterm**. But when I run `startx ~/.xinitrc i3` it passes i3 as the $1 argument everywhere else in the script.